# Remove changes from one element when event occurs on another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this program, clicking any box changes its color. However I want that on clicking one box, its color changes but on clicking the other box, its color should change but color from first box should disappear (ie return back to original state).

In a wider perspective, how can i return an element back to its original state once the event occurs on another element. (just like what happens when we add `:hover` effects in css, and the element returns to its original state when we remove mouse from it)

**EDIT** - In my original project, I have lots of divs with similar click effects. I want a general method that event on one element leads to removing all changes from all other elements.

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
div1.addEventListener("click", function() {this.style.backgroundColor="red";});
div2.addEventListener("click", function() {this.style.backgroundColor="red";});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any case give the DIVS a class

**Plain JS**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toggle'), function(el) {
    el.onclick = function() { // attach the handler
      [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toggle'), function(el) {
        el.classList.remove('active'); // remove from all
      });
      this.classList.add('active'); // add on current
    }
  });
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.active {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="toggle" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="toggle" id="div2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**jQuery** in case you want to try it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggle').on("click",function() {
    $('.toggle').removeClass("active"); // could add .not(this) here
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.active {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="toggle" id="div1"></div>
  <div class="toggle" id="div2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Smart and effective approach. +1

Comment: I was trying to understand your solution (i am a beginner and dont know much), is it that you have removed `.added` class from all elements and just added to one element which is clicked ?

Comment: I first remove the active from all elements and then add on clicked

Answer (score 1):

You just need to store the initial value for both `divs` background colour:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
var div1OriginalColour = div1.style.backgroundColor;
var div2OriginalColour = div1.style.backgroundColor;

div1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    div2.style.backgroundColor = div2OriginalColour;

    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});

div2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    div1.style.backgroundColor = div1OriginalColour;

    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/c4mLenb8/)

Answer (score 0):

Make another div style null..

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
div1.addEventListener("click", function() {this.style.backgroundColor="red"; div2.style.background = null;});
div2.addEventListener("click", function() {this.style.backgroundColor="red"; div1.style.background = null; });
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>    
  </body>
</html>
```